# Permission issue for apache

Tags: django, linux, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

Environment Details:

```
Amazon Ec2 Ubuntu 12.04
Django + mod_wsgi + python 2.6
web server: apache2
```

I have mounted a `10GB` `ebs volume` to an instance to `/mnt/ebs1/`. After mounting the volume and formatting, I have placed all my project files in `/mnt/ebs1/project`. the `wsgi` file is in `/mnt/ebs1/project/apache/django.wsgi`. The content of wsgi file is:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/mnt/ebs1/project')
sys.path.insert(1, '/mnt/ebs1')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.configs.common.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My `httpd.conf` file looks as:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python2.6

WSGIScriptAlias / /mnt/ebs1/project/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /mnt/ebs1/project>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /mnt/ebs1/project/apache>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /mnt/ebs1/project/static/
<Directory /mnt/ebs1/project/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The above configurations gives me `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server`.

I tried to find the user which is running apache using `ps aux` which is `www-data` and has group `www-data`. I have tried to change the ownership of `/mnt/ebs1` and its subdirectories using `chown -R www-data:www-data /mnt/ebs1` but that still does not solve the problem. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong or have missed?

Comment: This has something to do with the mounted volume, because similar kind of settings working fine on the other ec2 instance which is not ebs backed.

Comment: It looks like you have to declare DocumentRoot in your httpd.conf at first to excepted location.

Comment: No still getting the same forbidden error, I added `DocumentRoot /mnt/ebs1` in `httpd.conf` and restarted the server.

Comment: yes 2.6 I installed it manually, the default is 2.7.3, that is why I have mention `WSGIPythonHome` in `httpd.conf`

Comment: How do you have the volume mounted?  What attributes?

Comment: Thanks!  i have figured out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of:

https://serverfault.com/questions/441444/permission-issue-for-apache

WSGIPythonHome is wrong.

Go read response in duplicate.